# Правка .xml не вступает в силу на сайте

Tags: php

Редактирую, подключившись к серверу, в Notepad++ текст (чёрная подсветка). Необходимый для редактирования текст и расположение документа находил обычным поиском ОС (вроде по содержимому) в каталоге-директории public_html, предварительно скачав его с хостинга себе. 
После правки и сохранения документ на сервере изменяется (его уже можно скачивать видоизменённым), но фактически на страничке всё равно остаётся прежний текст. Чищу кэш в админке, браузере при настр. по умолч. - без изменений. 
Это аналогичный к моему случаю пример с текстом 30 % скидки на слайдере, строка в коде браузера 814: 
http://www.newsmartwave.net/magento/porto/index.php/demo1_en

Моя дом. страница такая же (только тот же вышеупомянутый текст на другой строке).
На хостинге у меня этот текст в blocks.xml (по адресу: public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/Porto/etc/import). Что ещё надо делать? Или, может, искать надо где-то в Мадженто админке, чтоб вносить данные изменения?

Comment: Кеширование настроено на сервере?

Comment: Пока не знаю где и как это..

Comment: Что за сервер? nginx?

Comment: Сервер Apache без услуги автоматического кеширования (не держит).

Answer (score 0):

Да, так по HTML контент не редактируется, это делается через админку (cms>статичные блоки). 
 P.S. Там может быть несколько страниц со списками Заголовков и при поиске всего необходимого надо их перелистывать, либо наставить (т. к. по умолч. - 20 записей), чтоб выводился больший показ на стр. 
Такова конфигурация темы Porto в Magento.